# What does the regular expression [.\d\D]* mean?

Tags: regex

What does `[.\\d\\D]*` mean.

I am trying to check a valid java main method statement by

```
java.matches("[.\\d\\D]*((public)\\s(static)\\s(void)\\s(main)\\((String)\\[\\]\\s(args)\\))[.\\d\\D]*");
```

what does that part mean?

Comment: You can http://regexpal.com/ it is really helpful

Comment: regex101.com is also useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `[.\d\D]*` means match:

`0 or more of anyone of these properties`

- digit
- non-digit
- literal dot

IMO this is not really required since this can effectively match anything and is equivalent of `.*` with DOTALL switch.

Comment: does .* also include the new line (\n)? One of my test cases ("\n //  ///*\"public static void main(String[] args)\"*/ \n ") is failing.

Comment: It is indeed odd. Even without DOTALL, `[\d\D]`, `[\s\S]`, or `[\w\W]` (i.e. no `.`) are the forms I've seen. The extra `.` makes it look like the original author just started throwing things together at random.

Comment: @SWKING It's odd because the `.` means nothing there (as it is covered by `[\d\D]`). Anyway, see DOTALL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

Comment: DOT will not match newline unless you use `(?s)` in front of your regex like `"a\nb".matches("(?s).*");` OR `Pattern.DOTALL` flag